# Evaluating models by Loglogss, AUC, and Accuracy

Tags: classification, auc, model-evaluation

I am evaluating three models (say, A, B, and C) by three different metrics: [Log-loss](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss), [AUC](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/AreaUnderCurve), and Accuracy.

The results show that

- Log-loss: C>A>B   (B has the best performance in terms of Log-loss)
- AUC: A>B>C        (A has the best performance in terms of AUC)
- Accuracy: C>A>B   (C has the best performance in terms of Accuracy)

It seems that none can dominate by all three metrics. How should I interpret this result and explain the possible reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very non-mathematical intuition:

- A has a higher accuracy than B, but a lower log-loss: it means A is shy, i.e. its probabilities tend to me closer to 0.5 than 0/1. B is bolder, i.e. its probalities are closer to 0/1, but makes more mistakes than A.
- A has a higher accuracy than B, but a lower AUROC: it means A is "better" than B for the threshold with which the accuracy was computed, but when considering all thresholds on average B is "better".